# How can I refresh a webpage without the browser asking if I want to resend again

Tags: javascript

I got the following code to refresh my webpage. It works great if I don't submit anything with POST but if i do, i get a message from the browser when my webpage refreshes (see image below)

```
location.reload(true);
```

I'm not looking for the browser settings tweak. I'm looking for alternative code to refresh without asking.
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is caused due to the page being requested by `POST` instead of `GET`. Refreshing will resubmit the `POST` data. You can force a get using `window.location = window.location.href;`.

If you want to allow people to reload the page through their browser controls then you will need to implement the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) which redirects to a `GET` after a `POST`.

Comment: This works but it doesn't remember my changes. if there a way to add the request paramaters to the end or something so that it remembers my settings after the refresh

Comment: Are you referring to the javascript or PRG pattern? The information that is being lost is what is being POSTed - that is the information that the prompt refers to. JavaScript is not able to access previously posted information. You could either add all of the posted information to the querystring if you implement the PRG pattern or resubmit the form via JavaScript. You will need to consider that if you resubmit the form then it will include any user changes and so (I guess) it is not really what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

This will request for a page and not a reload.

```
window.location = window.location;
```

Comment: This works but it doesn't remember my changes. if there a way to add the request paramaters to the end or something so that it remembers my settings after the refresh

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET that can be achieved by ViewState, if not, you have to do it manually. "Web is Stateless"

Answer (score 2):

[GET vs. POST](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

The solution: don't POST. GET is supposed to be idempotent (up to environmental changes), POST is supposed to be a modification.

After the POST, you should be performing an immediate GET to reload the page with the result of the POST. Then you can refresh at will.

Example:

page_1.html

```
<form method="POST" action="go.php"> ... </form>
```

go.php:

```
<?php
    // do stuff...
    header('Location: http://www.foo.com/page2.html');
?>
```

page2.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> location .reload (true); </script>
```

Comment: Solution 'don't use it' is not a solution. GET is sometimes insufficient due to the size limitations.

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled on the browser end and not yours (ie you CAN'T control it). If you want to show the user a page that can be refreshed without the repost option, you'll have to do it via a redirect following the post to a page that you retrieve with a GET not a POST.

Try a javascript redirect. Or alternatively, POST the information using AJAX which will mean refresh reloads the original page, not the results of your ajax post.

Answer (score 0):

you can save your data to window.name and use the window.location = window.location.href trick. and when onload, check if you have data in window.name, get it back and remove it from there. i use the window.name as "session" storage quite often for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm spanish speaker, I´ll do my best)
In my case,  I have a button to looking for open tickets in a DB, so, i need to press that button every time that I wanna know if there are new ones, I resolved with the next javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
    setTimeout('document.getElementById("btn_busca_ticket").click()', 10000);
</script>
```

where 10000 is the time between every refresh, (10 seconds)

if you don't have a button, you can create a hidden one with an ID and a submit 
(it's not so elegant, but works for me)